# Use Keyboard.IsKeyDown in C# console application

Tags: c#, console-application, keyboard-events

I'm writing an console application witch Displaying certain data on the console screen, than checking for user input from the keyboard and finally handleing it by need. all single threaded.

For that i tried using Keyboard.IsKeyDown Method from System.Windows.Input namespace. and visual studio wo'nt allow it.
Does anyone knows why and can help me?
I dont see other way implementing that logic using only one thread and no timer's.

Comment: Polling the keyboard in a console app requires Console.KeyAvailable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Console.ReadKey()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readkey.aspx) to read input from the keyboard in a console application.

Note that this is a blocking call. If you don't want to block, combine with `Console.KeyAvailable`. For example, this program will loop and display if a key is pressed every 10th of a second:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    do
    {
        if (Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
            var key = Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine(key.Key);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No key pressed");
        }
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    } while (true);
}
```

Comment: ReadKey is a blocking call - _"The ReadKey method waits, that is, blocks on the thread issuing the ReadKey method, until a character or function key is pressed."_ - don't think that's what OP wants.

Comment: As suggested in the question comments, though, this would work if partnered with `Console.KeyAvailable` - like in [this documentation sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Good points. I've updated the answer to reflect this, and added an example.