# C# Keyboard access

Tags: c#, keyboard

I am advanced in Java, but a bloody beginner in C#.
I think my intention is pretty clear:
I want to print out the 'A' character as soon as it is down on the keyboard, but it doesn't work :( I already added the PresentationCore.dll.
It is fundamental for me to do this via the Keyboard, not the console.
Thanks in advance for your advice. Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    Console.WriteLine("This is a crappy programm, which doesn't work the way it is supposed to do!");
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.A))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("A is down! A is down!");
                }
            }
            catch (System.InvalidOperationException e)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" -- What does it do, what should it do?  What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: Have you looked at KeyDown events?

Comment: as I mentioned: It should print out the line "A is down! A is down!" as soon as 'A'(the character on the keyboard) is down.
And well, it doesn't print out the line as soon 'A' is down :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use Keyboard.IsKeyDown in C# console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43766287/use-keyboard-iskeydown-in-c-sharp-console-application)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Console Applications have confusion what the main thread is.

Place this attribute above your `static void Main(string[] args)`:

```
[STAThread]
```

This indicates that the COM threading model for an application is a single-threaded-apartment or STA.

**Edit:**

Also, remember to add a reference to `WindowsBase.dll`, as that's where the `Key` enum is located!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Console.KeyAvailable)
{
    if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.A)
        Console.WriteLine("A is down! A is down!");
}
```

And you don't need the PresentationCore.dll now.